# Async pipe with rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

I have a little problem in async pipe
Here is my case , 
I need to run nested observables in async pipe in html because i use on push strategy and i dont want to use some workarounds or change detector reference .
My problem is , when i run the code below only the first observable is called 
Should i add return statements? Or whats the problem ?

Ts code

```
this.http.getUsers(criteria)
.pipe(map(data=>{
data.users.map(user=>{
this.http.getUserData(user.id)
.pipe(map(res=>{user.data=res.data}))}}
```

Html code

`<div *ngFor=let user of users$ | async> </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a switchMap and you need to assign an observable to the users$ property.

```
users$ = this.http.getUsers(criteria).pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.http.getUserData(user.id)),
  map(res => res.data)
);
```

Comment: I replaced the map with the switch map and i did assign the useres to observable and still only the first observable is called

Comment: Switch map into forkjoin.

Comment: Okay i forgot a brace ,  it worked according to adrian code it has ran successfully,  and both observables were called but the users werent loaded in html

Comment: Did you do anything with the user template variable to display it like <div *ngFor=let user of users$ | async>{{ user | json }}</div> ? Your template code just creates an empty div per user and doesn't use the user variable.